# AMP Iframe CSS Media Queries

Tags: html, css, amp-html

I've defined some media queries on my css and some AMP Iframes. What is happening is that the AMP ignores the media queries although the generated css shows the definition of the media query.

```
.table__td-span {
    display: none
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .table__td-span {
        display:inline-block;
    }
}
```

I think that maybe AMP Iframes by definition not apply the media queries for sizes bigger than mobile? Is a common behaviour? Or there is some trick? What's more is that if I access on the URL of the Iframe, there the media query works.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with `!important`?

Comment: Jerdine Sabio `!important` has nothing to do here. Because is not that the properties are override, the problem is that the media query is ignore.

Comment: AMP does not affect media queries. Can you please post a full example include the amp-iframe?